# Another characteristic of subsets of (finite) power sets

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, partitions, definitions

Consider a finite set $M$, its power set $\mathcal{P}(M)$ and a subset $S$ of the power set, i.e. $S \subset \mathcal{P}(M)$.

Consider as a characteristic of $S$ the function $f_S: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, which assigns to each $n$ the number $f_S(n)$ of elements of $M$ that are contained in exactly $n$ elements of $S$ (which are subsets of $M$).

Easy facts about the characteristic $f_S$:

- $f_S(i) \leq |M|$
- $f_S(i) = 0$ when $i > 2^{|M|-1}$
- $\Sigma_i f_S(i) = |M|$
- $f_S(1) = |M|$ iff $S$ is a partition

The function $f_S$ measures in some sense how (and how strongly) the elements of $S$ (which are subsets of $M$) overlap.

Has this characteristic been studied in its own right? If so, under which name?

Comment: One more easy fact: $\sum_i \, i \, f_S(i) = \sum_{s \in S} |s|$.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but this is basically one half of the degree sequence of the bipartite graph encoding incidences of $S$: that is, with vertices $M \cup S$ and edges $(x,s)$ when $M \ni x \in s \in S$. The degree sequence (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph#Degree) is the pair of lists of degrees of vertices in $M$, and in $S$; your $f_S$ is a tally or frequency count for the $M$ part of the degree sequence.

Comment: This definitely helps!